# how to search jsonb column in postgresql ( not nested column )

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

my schema :

```
create table blog (
  id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title varchar,
  tags jsonb
);
```

my db:
[image]

my query:

```js
const tags = "horr";
const query = `SELECT * FROM blog where tags like '%${tags}%'`;
```

what I am  want:

now I am want to get only "tags" column include **"horror"**. but I wanna use just **"horr"**

I know this query is not work. but wanna do like this below

```json
"rows": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "horror stroy",
      "tags": [
        "sad",
        "horror"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest all tags in order to be able to use a LIKE condition

```
select b.*
from blog b
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements_text(b.tags) as x(tag)
              where tag ilike 'horr%');
```